# Is it ok to not include phone number on resume?

Tags: resume, phone

I have a phone but I very much seldom use it. I prefer the communication through email (which I had already included in my job resume).

Is that okay if I don't include a phone number in my job resume since phone is not the best way to contact me?

Comment: This is very much location dependant.  In the UK, 95% of IT jobs go through recruitment agencies, and even if you do include your contact details they will remove them before forwarding your CV onto the client.  My email address and phone number have not been on my CV for over 10 years

Comment: Is it OK with you if they don't contact you?

Comment: I was wondering the same, as I dislike to receive calls from masked number anytime.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Should I include my phone**

Even if seldom used and your preference is email, you also have to consider the preference of others. I personally prefer to contact people by phone then in person. (you can't get a good read on a person's personality via email.)

That said, I'd probably just skip past your resume since I get applications by the dozen. Now if you were one of only a few I received I might email you asking for a phone number, but honestly it'll hurt your odds of consideration.

**What if I prefer Email?**

You can specifically mark email as preferred, but offer the phone as backup. If you REALLY want to only be contacted by email, by all means you can omit it, but it could potentially cost you opportunities with those who do not prefer email.

Comment: I hope on your job postings you emphasis the phone number requirement.

Comment: @JeffO - Other than "potential applicants will be contacted by phone for interviews" I don't think it should be an explicit 'requirement' per se.

Comment: Well, /proffered/ is clearly a typo for /preferred/, but I'm not sure about /then/. Do you mean "I prefer to contact people by phone first, and then in person second" or do you mean "I find it preferable to contact people by phone than to contact them in person"?

Comment: By the way, I **strongly** suspect that your hiring practices count as discrimination against deaf people. You should probably reconsider that.

Comment: There are many ways for deaf people to access phone systems, at least in the US, and I would suspect in many other countries.

Comment: As long as the answerer 'prefers' to contact by phone, and does not *exlusively* contact by phone, I don't think that's discrimination, so long as they make allowances when necessary.  Though double-checking with HR wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @TRIG I did mean Then not than. (basically I chat with you on the phone, and if you check out there call you in) As far as Deaf goes... I'm trying to picture a way we could accommodate a blind or deaf person here. Not that we wouldn't try, but I've never had someone with those disabilities apply. Now I wouldn't just toss any phoneless resume in the trash automatically, but if I have a ton of applications, I'm going to cut a bunch, this starts with exp, technical background, notable red flags, etc. but as I get further I cut them for lesser and lesser reasons until it's manageable.

Comment: @RualStorge , you prefer to phone. Do you schedule a timeslot for an availability? I find rather rude that some recruiters cold call and expects the receiver to spend 30 minutes.

Answer (score 7):

I'm thinking a little out of the box here, but why not sign up for a Google Voice account or something similar, and list that number on your resume?    I see a couple of advantages to this:

1. You can route the Google Voice voicemail notification to your email
2. You limit the spread of your "real" phone number and can more or less ensure that any calls to the Google Voice number are related to your resume

This is kind of a "best of both worlds" approach that satisfies RualStorge's concern about omitting the phone number.  I have done this in previous job searches and it has worked out very well.

If you decide to do it this way, be sure and put a professional voice mail message on your Google Voice account.

Comment: +1 Even if Google Voice is not available to you there are many VoIP-to-phone services that offer disposable numbers and redirecting capabilities.